# Why read.table gives connection error while execute within a function

Tags: r, plot, connection

I have a data that looks like [this](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=i8XXxUu0):

```
Probes  Gene.symbol some.kk.06  some.sp.06  some.ln.06  some.kk.06  some.sp.06
1419083_at  Tnfsf11 0   1.273   0.976   0   0.964
1419318_at  Saa4    1.134   0   0   1.916   0
1442255_at  --- 0   1.104   1.417   0   0.761
1421025_at  Agpat1  0   1.058   0.976   0   1.02
1427071_at  Fbxo42  1.094   1.012   1.137   1.589   1.308
```

What I want to do is to plot a dendogram with the code below:

```
#!/u21/neversaint/.r/bin/Rscript
library(gplots);


plot.hclust  <- function(inputfile,clust.height) {


    dat.some <- read.table(inputfile,na.strings=NA, sep="\t",header=TRUE);
    print(head(dat.some))


    rownames(dat.some) <- do.call(paste,c(dat.some[c("Probes","Gene.symbol")],sep=" "))
    dat.some <- dat.some[,!names(dat.some) %in% c("Probes","Gene.symbol")]
    dat.some <- dat.some

    # Clustering and distance function
    hclustfunc <- function(x) hclust(x, method="complete")
    distfunc <- function(x) dist(x,method="maximum")


    # Select based on FC, as long as any of them >= anylim
    dat.some <- dat.some[ apply(dat.some, 1,function(x) any (x >= anylim)), ]
    nrow(dat.some);


    # Clustering functions
    height <- clust.height; 

    # Define output file name
    dendoout <- paste("some.pafc.dendo.",anylim,".h",height,".default.pdf",sep="");

    # Compute distance and clusteirn function
    d.some <- distfunc(dat.some)
    fit.some <- hclustfunc(d.some)
    str(fit.some)

    # Plot the hierarchical dendogram without heatmap
    pdf(file=dendoout,width=120,height=27);
    plot(fit.some)
    dev.off()
}

plot.hclust("http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=i8XXxUu0",clust.height=3);
```

But it prints this error:

```
Error in read.table(inputfile, na.strings = NA, sep = "\t", header = TRUE) : 
  'file' must be a character string or connection
```

How can I resolve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're overriding the generic method for plotting `hclust` objects by naming your function `plot.hclust` such that when you call `plot(fit.some)` in the second last line of your function, you're actually recursively calling the function from within itself, but with `fit.some` as the inputfile instead of a url or filename.

Naming your function something other than `plot.hclust` should resolve the issue you're encountering, as then `plot(fit.some)` should have the intended behaviour.